# Creating Dictionary in Python via Multiple for Loops

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I know the syntax in the following is off, but I'm having trouble figuring out how this should be written. What I'm trying to do is take the list "list" and create a dictionary where the keys are the combination of each words with each other word that isn't itself and the value for every key is 0. Here's my broken code:

```
lst = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
for words in lst:
    first = words
    for words in lst:
        if words != first:
            scores = {'%s + %s': 0, % (first, words)}
```

Dictionary would look like this:

```
scores = {'human + loud': 0, 'human + big': 0, 'loud + big': 0, 'loud + human': 0, 'big + loud': 0, 'big + human': 0}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edited: To change list type to lst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a more compact function.

```
import itertools
scores = {}
for a,b in itertools.permutations(('human', 'loud', 'big'), 2):
    scores["{0} + {1}".format(a,b)] = 0
print scores
```

Comment: Very nice, goes well with a dict comprehension also `{' + '.join(x):0 for x in permutations(lst, 2)}`

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax issue with the dictionary assignment line, but the more important issue is that you're re-assigning the dictionary every time.

Instead, create the dictionary at the start and then just add to it.

Finally list is not a good variable name because it collides with the name of the type.

```
mylist = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
scores = {}
for w in mylist:
    for v in mylist:
        if w != v:
            scores['%s + %s'  % (w, v)] = 0

print scores
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `list` is a bad variable name as it conflicts with the list type

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
lst = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
scores = {}
for f in lst:
    for s in lst:
        if f != s:
            scores['{0} + {1}'.format(f, s)] = 0

print scores
```

As such:

```
>>> lst = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
>>> scores = {}
>>> for f in lst:
...     for s in lst:
...         if f != s:
...             scores['{0} + {1}'.format(f, s)] = 0
... 
>>> print scores
{'human + big': 0, 'big + loud': 0, 'big + human': 0, 'human + loud': 0, 'loud + big': 0, 'loud + human': 0}
>>>
```

Comment: Wow -- super fast. This works. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Additionally, if you use enumerate on the top for loop, you can iterate the sublist in the second loop, starting at index+1, so you don't have to check if you are that word...because your words are unique, right?

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea - here's your basic logic with the syntax fixed. The two primary changes are: 1) you need to name the iterator variable in your inner loop something different than the iterator variable in your outer loop, otherwise the scopes will conflict, and 2) to add things to dictionaries, use the [key] index notation rather than trying to create a whole new dictionary with curly brace notation.

```
list = ['human', 'loud', 'big']
scores = {}
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list)): 
        if i != j:
            key = list[i] + " + " + list[j]
            scores[key] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my snippet that worked. I recommend creating the dictionary and then just adding to it.

```
    scores = {}

    lst = ('human', 'loud', 'big')

    for words in list:
        first = words
        for words in list:
            if words != first:
                scores.update({first + " + " +  words: 0}) 

    print scores
```

I'd recommend changing some of your variable names to differentiate between the words being used in each nested list. As then you can do away with the 'first' variable entirely.

```
    scores = {}

    lst = ('human', 'loud', 'big')

    for word1 in list:
        for word2 in list:
            if word2 != word1:
                scores.update({word1 + " + " +  word2: 0}) 

    print scores
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations as comb
l = ['human', 'loud', 'big']
scores = dict((" + ".join(pair), 0)
              for ordered_pair in comb(l, 2)
                for pair in (ordered_pair, reversed(ordered_pair)))
```